# Cannot create hook_menu subitems with proper position in administrative menu

Tags: 7, routes, hooks, ubercart, navigation

I would like to add an hook_menu item and generate its expandable subitems under ubercart's 'admin/store/' path.

For now I have:

```
function activit_menu() {

  $items['admin/store/products-fabrics'] = array(
      'title' => 'Látky produktov',
      'access arguments' => array('access administration menu'),
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

      $items = array_merge($items, activit_generate_products_fabrics_menu_items());

    }



function activit_generate_products_fabrics_menu_items() {

  $products = activit_get_products_with_fabrics();

  $items = array();

  foreach($products as $product) {

    $items['admin/store/products-fabrics/'.$product['nid']] = array(
        'title' => $product['title'],
        'access arguments' => array('access administration menu'),
        'file' => 'd_forms.inc',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('activit_eshop_fabrics_of_products_form'),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION
    );

  }

  return $items;

}
```

But this code will create both 'products-fabrics' item and all its subitems at the same level in administration menu and 'admin/store/products-fabrics' item is not expendable. After clicking at 'products-fabrics' item you will see the same andimistration page as aftre clicking at 'admin/store' plus the subitems links at the top oft he page. I can hide this page with css an let only the subitems to be visible. But I need to create expandable 'admin/store/products-fabrics' item in order to be able to click directly at 'admin/store/products-fabrics/subitem'.

I was trying all the possible item types but no success. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the MENU_LOCAL_ACTION type for your sub-menus is not the good choice.

The Menu [item types documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/group/menu_item_types/7.x) tell us :

> MENU_LOCAL_ACTION : Menu type -- An action specific to the parent,
>   usually rendered as a link.

If you want to have a menu with sub-menus, you need to also define a page call back for it. You can use the system_admin_menu_block_page, witch display a bloc with all the sub-menus links.

```
// Main menu link
$items['admin/store/products-fabrics'] = array(
    'title' => 'Látky produktov',
    'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

// Sub menu links
$items['admin/store/products-fabrics/'.$product['nid']] = array(
    'title' => $product['title'],
    'access arguments' => array('access administration menu'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('activit_eshop_fabrics_of_products_form'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'file' => 'd_forms.inc',
);
```

Comment: No, it does not work. Subitems are still directly in 'admin/store/subitem' and 'admin/store/products-fabrics' is not even displayed.

Comment: Maybe you have to disable your module, clear the cash, and enable your module again.
It's append to me that modifications on a menu structure are not taken by Drupal when the module is already installed...

Comment: After some changes and clearing cache multiple times it started to work. Then I changed the code back to your original form as you've posted and now it works. Seems like drupal has some problems clearing cahce for admin menu. Thanks.